# What's the purpose of using & before a function's argument?

Tags: php, function, variables, reference

I saw some function declarations like this:

```
function boo(&$var){
 ...
}
```

what does the `&` character do?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's a pass by reference. The variable inside the function "points" to the same data as the variable from the calling context.

```
function foo(&$bar)
{
  $bar = 1;
}

$x = 0;
foo($x);
echo $x; // 1
```

Comment: so it behaves similar to when using `global $var`

Comment: @Alex, kind of true, but there's two big differences: 1) it works for non-global scopes (functions calling other functions) and 2) it doesn't depend on the inner function knowing the name of the variable. References as function arguments are easier to debug and less error prone than global variables, although some of the same concerns (e.g., unexpected changes to a variable) do still apply.

Comment: thank you. looks useful when I want a function to return more than one variable :) (it's not really a "return" but something like that :))

Comment: Alex, true. This is a common paradigm, even used in PHPs core library, eg: http://php.net/parse_str

Comment: I have one more question: I tried using this without declaring the `$x` variable (mine is boolean) before calling the function and it seems to work, and I don't get any notices telling me that the variable is not initialized. So is that ok to do?

Comment: For regular function arguments, you would get an `E_NOTICE` if you did that. But you do not get one if it is a reference. This is probably because many people use them for out-values (returning multiple values) and such a notice would be inconvenient. So if the variable is "write only" inside the function, most people would probably be okay with it not being initialized.

Comment: Thanks the nice little example. I used the `php -a` interactive console to try your example a few other situations.

Comment: Good. PHP reference : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference

Answer (score 27):

Basically if you change `$var` inside the function, it gets changed outside. For example:

```
$var = 2;

function f1(&$param) {
    $param = 5;
}

echo $var; //outputs 2
f1($var);
echo $var; //outputs 5
```

Comment: I have spent the past 20 minutes googling and reading to figure this out.  Your explanation is by far the clearest I've come across.  That little difference of using $var and $param makes it so clear.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It accepts a reference to a variable as the parameter.

This means that any changes that the function makes to the parameter (eg, `$var = "Hi!"`) will affect the variable passed by the calling function.

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand ( & ) before a variable ( & $foo ) overrides pass by value to specify that you want to pass the variable by reference instead.

For example if you have this:

```
function doStuff($variable) {
     $variable++;
}

$foo = 1;

doStuff($foo);
echo $foo; 
// output is '1' because you passed the value, but it doesn't alter the original variable

doStuff( &$foo ); // this is deprecated and will throw notices in PHP 5.3+
echo $foo; 
// output is '2' because you passed the reference and php will alter the original variable.
```

It works both ways.

```
function doStuff( &$variable) {
     $variable++;
}

$foo = 1;

doStuff($foo);
echo $foo; 
// output is '2' because the declaration of the function requires a reference.
```

Comment: Your second example that uses call-time  pass-by-reference `doStuff(&$foo)` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: My comment might be misleading now with the extra code. So to be clear: `function doStuff(&$variable) {}` is fine, but `doStuff(&$variable);` at call time is not.

Answer (score 2):

It is [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

If you are familiar with C pointers, it is like passing a pointer to the variable.

Except there is no need to dereference it (like C).

Comment: +1.  Was wondering when reading the above if this was what pointers meant in C; with your confirmation it now makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

you are passing $var as reference, meaning the actual value of $var gets updated when it is modified inside boo function

example:

```
function boo(&$var) {
   $var = 10;
}

$var = 20;
echo $var; //gets 20
boo($var);
echo $var //gets 10
```

Answer (score -2):

If any function starts with ampersand(&), It means its call by Reference function. It will return a reference to a variable instead of the value.

```
function reference_function( &$total ){
  $extra = $total + 10;
}

$total = 200;
reference_function($total) ;
echo $total; //OutPut 210
```

Comment: Please explain what this adds, when it appears to be a more or less direct copy of the accepted answer (with a typo in the penultimate line)?

Comment: I have improved my answer.
I am trying to explain if you need to modify direct in variable then you can call like above.
Thanks